# Cloudera : SemanticException No valid privileges Required privileges for this query

Tags: hive, cloudera

while creating the table (with user admin) with Hive I have this error :

```
Your query has the following error(s):

Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException No valid privileges Required privileges for this query: Server=server1->Db=*->Table=+->action=insert;Server=server1->Db=*->Table=+->action=select;
```

I do not understand why admin has not enough privileges, what should I do to solve the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have authentication and authorization enabled? Did you properly setup Sentry, Kerberos authentication. Also you should follow Kerberos authentication for Hive documentation. Databases and tables stored by Hive in /user/hive/warehouse are exclusively owned by Hive admin user. Then I will create admin role for hive group and add mappings for this user. Did your admin user authenticated properly? It is local user or Kerberos principal?

Answer (score -1):

Login to terminal and run this command `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 -R /user/hive/warehouse` and try creating databases/tables.

The user admin in hue need not have permissions under hdfs location /user/hive/warehouse where all the Hive tables will be pointing to.